# How to set table TR exact to image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an image in a table, but the table seems to be bigger than the image for the height. How can I make the image height and the table height the same?
My code is as below:

```html
<table class="row" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:100%; position:relative; display:block; padding:0px; "> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
      <td class="wrapper last center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; position:relative; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 

        <table class="twelve columns center desktop-only" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:580px; padding:0; display:table !important; "> 
          <tbody> 
            <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
              <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
                  <p><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/greeting_header.jpg" alt="eO Logo White.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="max-width: 600px;" /></p>
                </div></td> 
            </tr> 
          </tbody> 
        </table> 

      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

I want the image height and table height to be the same so there is no extra spacing.

Comment: You wrapped your `img` in a `p`, and `p` has default margins. Btw, `p` is not meant to be used as an image wrapper, it is meant for text.

Comment: In your image you have a max-width. Can't you just set the height for the image and set it the same as the table? or is the image dynamic and you want the table to adjust accordingly to every image?

Comment: i want the table to adjust with the image heigt

Comment: I also need to say, that code is as error prone as it gets, with mixed internal and external CSS. It also contains so much unnecessary styling, and you should really have it cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this css**

```css
img{display:block}
p{margin:0 !important;}
```

```html
<table class="row" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:100%; position:relative; display:block; padding:0px; "> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                          <td class="wrapper last center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; position:relative; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 

                            <table class="twelve columns center desktop-only" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:580px; padding:0; display:table !important; "> 
                              <tbody> 
                                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                                  <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                                    <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
                                      <p><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/greeting_header.jpg" alt="eO Logo White.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="max-width: 600px;" /></p>
                                    </div></td> 
                                </tr> 
                              </tbody> 
                            </table> 

                          </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table>
```

Comment: In this code image height and table height is same http://prntscr.com/lxtgzc, You need anything else?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting height inline. Your `img` is wrapped by `p`

Answer (score -1):

If you set the image width as 100% and just fix size of td of your table, then you can get image and table size as same.

```html
<table class="row" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:100%; position:relative; display:block; padding:0px; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left">
      <td class="wrapper last center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; position:relative; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; "
        align="left" valign="top">

        <table class="twelve columns center desktop-only" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:580px; padding:0; display:table !important; ">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left">
              <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; "
                align="left" valign="top">
                <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
                  <p><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/universeconquest/images/e/e6/Sample.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20171003194302" alt="eO Logo White.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="width:100%" /></p>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```